# saving the logs in text file which gets generated in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to save the logs in text file  which gets generated in selenium webdriver?

I know how to log normal logs in java like using logger.
Below is the step which i tried to log.

```
Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();
PropertyConfigurator.configure("data/config/log4j.properties");
FileAppender appender = (FileAppender)logger.getAppender("file");
String logFilePath ="C:\\Users\\priyarsi\\Desktop\\LdapLog.txt";
appender.setFile(logFilePath);
appender.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
appender.setAppend(true);
appender.activateOptions();
log.debug("Hello this is an debug message");
log.info("Hello this is an info message");
```

Can anyone please help me in logging selenium webdriver output to a text file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out -

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=../AutoLogs.log
#log4j.appender.file.File=${file.name}
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L %t - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L %t - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try logging **Log4j API.** It is very easy to understand and implement. Perform following steps:

1. Download Log4j jars from (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html)
2. Add downloaded jars to project's build path.
3. Create a new XML file – log4j.xml and place it under the Project root folder.
4. Add new xml file or you can customise it the way you want. (http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/log4j-logging/)
5. Create new Java Class and paste following code:
   package utility;

   ```
   import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
   public class Log {

   // Initialize Log4j logs
   private static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(Log.class.getName());//
   // This is to print log for the beginning of the test case, as we usually
   // run so many test cases as a test suite

   public static void startTestCase(String sTestCaseName) {

       Log.info("****************************************************************************************");
       Log.info("****************************************************************************************");
       Log.info("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$                 " + sTestCaseName + "       $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
       Log.info("****************************************************************************************");
       Log.info("****************************************************************************************");
   }

   // This is to print log for the ending of the test case
   public static void endTestCase(String sTestCaseName) {
       Log.info("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX             " + "-E---N---D-" + "             XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
       Log.info("X");
       Log.info("X");
       Log.info("X");
       Log.info("X");

   }

   // Need to create these methods, so that they can be called
   public static void info(String message) {
       Log.info(message);
   }

   public static void warn(String message) {
       Log.warn(message);
   }

   public static void error(String message) {
       Log.error(message);
   }

   public static void fatal(String message) {
       Log.fatal(message);
   }

   public static void debug(String message) {
       Log.debug(message);
     }
   }
   ```
6. Call above methods in your test scripts.